# Spring @Async AdviceMode.ASPECTJ triggers bean creation errors

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aop, aspectj

Faced the problem when migrating to spring boot 2. I have such configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)
public class AsyncConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer, AsyncConfigurer
{
   // ...
}
```

The problim is that when I set mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ I am getting exceptions with custom beans creation:

```
    @Bean
    public EhCacheCleaner ehcacheCleaner()
    {
        EhCacheCleaner cacheCleaner = new EhCacheCleaner();
        cacheCleaner.setCacheManagersNames("hibernateCache", "sampleCache");
        return cacheCleaner;
    }
```

### Exception:

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheCleanerService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'ehcacheCleaner'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ehcacheCleaner' defined in class path resource [com/panbet/externalbet/core/config/AsyncConfig.class]: No matching factory method found: factory bean 'asyncConfig'; factory method 'ehcacheCleaner()'. Check that a method with the specified name exists and that it is non-static.

If I remove **mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ**, this exception disaperes, BUT @Async methods not work. The exception is:

BeanFactory must be set on AnnotationAsyncExecutionAspect to access qualified executor

How to get rid of this? What is the reason of exceptions? Thank you.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve with async operation??

Comment: Would you mind posting the code that you refer to? i.e. you refer to CacheCleanerService... it'd be useful if you included that.

Comment: Other question is if you're using advice mode aspectj are you running the aspectj compiler when compiling? or have you setup load time weaving?